# Rotate tcpdump stdout file by time

Tags: stdout, tcpdump

I have a long running tcpdump that runs over ssh which outputs to a file.

```
ssh remotehost.example.com -p "tcpdump -i eth0 -w - " > capture-`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M'`.pcap
```

How can I rotate that file by day or week? It is important to not duplicate or lose any content.

Answer (score 0):

From the tcpdump man page:

> ```
>   -G     If specified, rotates the dump file specified with the -w option every  rotate_sec‐
>           onds  seconds.  Savefiles will have the name specified by -w which should include a
>           time format as defined by strftime(3).  If no time format is  specified,  each  new
>           file will overwrite the previous.
>           If  used  in  conjunction  with  the  -C  option,  filenames  will take the form of
>           `file<count>'.
> ```

For example, if you want to rotate every 10 seconds:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -G 10 -w capture-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.pcap
```

In your case, you can rotate daily like so:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -G 86400 -w capture-%Y%m%d-%H%M.pcap
```

Comment: I am piping tcpdump output through SSH so I need the rotation to happen on a different machine. This doesn't appear to work in my situation.